# ctxhx.exe stop working when importing oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle

After exporting oracle database dump file, using exp command and having no warnings, I am trying to import it using imp command. The import process works great till the end of the last table, after which following windows error comes:

"ctxhx.exe has stopped working"

The import process continues in dos window indefinitely like for hours while windows periodically shows the above error after I close down the pop up window. Seems the import cannot be done until this exe problem is solved.

I have done a complete uninstall of oracle 10g r2 database from my system, using the Oracle Universal Installer and after that cleaning registry as well as home folder etc. Then installed back same oracle 10g r2 fresh.

I have exported and imported using exp and imp commands the same database many times before and never have a problem.

I am using OracleText to index pdf files on hard disk, therefore preference, index and directory is created.

The problem is in development machine only. The production server with exact same configuration (windows version, oracle edition and version etc) is working fine.

Everytime I import the database on development machine I run the following script:

```
connect
sys as sysdba
<password>

drop user dms cascade;
create user dms identified by pqrs;

grant connect to dms;
grant create session to dms;

grant create any sequence to dms;
grant drop any sequence to dms;

grant create any directory to dms;
grant drop any directory to dms;

grant dba to dms;
grant sysdba to dms;

grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_ddl to dms;

create or replace directory documents as 'c:\uploadedFiles';

quit;

c:\>imp
```

The dump files creates database (schema + data + procedures etc) of only one user dms.

Before running imp command I made sure to copy the pdf files in the said folder on c drive.

The folder is set as read-only and I cannot change it because everytime I change it, from windows or dos, it automatically set back as read-only. This shouldn't be a problem because on production it has same read-only setting and is running fine.

windows server 2008. oracle 10g r2 enterprise edition. 64 bit machines and oracle.

Comment: Are you on the base install of 10gR2 (10.2.0.1), or have you patched up to the terminal patchset (10.2.0.5)? If you're hitting a bug you might find it's been resolved...

Comment: You'd need to raise a service request with Oracle to get details and confirm the symptoms, but there seem to be some bugs in this area that are fixed in 10.2.0.4. Not sure why the production machine wouldn't be affected, if it also on the base release, unless the `exp`/`imp` is only happening on development. Are you not able to apply the patch sets?

Comment: Exporting from production server, importing that on development machine. Importing working fine on production server of the same dump. Link of patch please.